# Microsoft Graph API - error on getting shares

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I m using Microsoft Graph API to get a list of all available shares as follows.

```
GraphServiceClient _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(myAuthProvider);
var shares = _graphClient.Shares.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

I get the following error.

> The request is malformed or incorrect

Other API calls for drives, sites, users, groups etc. work fine. Only this request fails. Why? How to find all available shares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `shareId` or `sharing URL`.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var sharedDriveItem = await graphClient.Shares["{sharedDriveItem-id}"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

To encode a sharing URL, use base64 encode the URL

Reference:

[Accessing shared DriveItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Encoding sharing URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#encoding-sharing-urls)

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. I cannot mark it as an answer because my goal is different. Your reply explains how to get ONE shared item. Instead, I want to get a list of ALL shared items. It was my guess that Shares() query without argument will return such a list. But it does not work. I will improve text of question to make it more clear.

Comment: @BorisZinchenko Sure. There is no API to get all shared files. You can list only files shared with the signed-in user.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It is negative answer to my question. But it is the answer.